# Xamarin.Forms get a list of sdcard files from Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I Use Xamarin.Forms for Android app and trying to get a list of files from cdcard.
This code:

```
var dir = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory();
```

returns the local path not the path to the cd card /storage/emulated/0

I tried using NuGet FilePicker:

```
var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
string pathFile = file.FilePath;
```

if the local file path outputs normally, then for sdcard it can 't get the file path either and returns content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/2352-3212%3Atest.txt

I have a question, how do I access files on sdcard? Other applications work with sdcard, such as audio and video players.

p.s. All necessary permissions for writing and reading from sdcard in the app are added.

Comment: I expected to get the exact path to the file on SDcard, not the path content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/2352-3212%3Atest.txt
and this is content: // [Authority] / [path] / [id]
but I still can not open the file from SDcard

Comment: Have you use the below method ? I could get the absolutepath like `/storage/emulated/0/...`

Comment: The method below does not see files on sdcard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the document said "**Android**: the FilePath property may contain a content URI that starts with `content://`"，you should convert the Uri to the filePath.

and here is a method whithout using FilePicker nuget,you should use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) in the PCL project,call the android native method.

1.create an interface in PCL project :

```
public interface IGetFiles
{
    List<string> GetFiles(string filetype);// you could set what type of file do you want
}
```

2.the let your MainActivity implement the interface :

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MainActivity))]//dont miss this line
namespace EntryCa.Droid
{
   public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity,IGetFiles
   {
       private static MainActivity Instance;
       List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
         ...
         Instance = this;
         ...
       }

       public List<string> GetFiles(string filetype)
       {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(Instance, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 1);
            var path2 = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory;
            return Search_Dir(path2, filetype); ;

       }

       public List<string> Search_Dir(Java.IO.File dir,string fileType)
       {

          Java.IO.File[] FileList = dir.ListFiles();

          if (FileList != null)
          {
            for (int i = 0; i < FileList.Length; i++)
            {

                if (FileList[i].IsDirectory)
                {
                    Search_Dir(FileList[i], fileType);
                }
                else
                {


                    if (FileList[i].Name.EndsWith(fileType))
                    {
                        fileList.Add(FileList[i].AbsolutePath);
                        //here you have that file.
                        //System.Console.WriteLine(FileList[i].AbsolutePath);
                    }
                }
             }
            return fileList;
           }
           return null;
        }
   }

}
```

3. call in your page :

```
List<string>  files =   DependencyService.Get<IGetFiles>().GetFiles(".txt");
```

Comment: 3. System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' :(

Comment: could you show your codes? Let's talk [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209966/chat)

Comment: unfortunately my reputation is too low to chat. My problem in PCL project.

Comment: need a way to open the file from SDcard using the path.

Comment: you could look at [read and write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#reading-or-writing-to-files-on-internal-storage),only change the internal storage path to your path.